# Angular Material Paginator Issue On Material Data Table

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

I have a data table populating from a service, everything works fine except when I hover over the arrow to paginate I get this error

[image]

I have:

```
   ngOnInit() {
      this.dataTableSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   }
```

and am also resetting when I get data from the service like:

```
processedTransactions.subscribe(transactions => {

      this.dataTableSource = newMatTableDataSource<DataTableRow(this.dataTableData);
          this.dataTableSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataTableSource.sort = this.sort;
})
```

html is:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="length"
              [pageSize]="pageSize"
              [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
              >
</mat-paginator>
```

with:

```
  length = 100;
  pageSize = 5;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [10, 20, 30];
```

Why am I getting this error when I hover over the arrow to paginate?

Also when I hard code the data it still gives the same error

Comment: can you also post <mat-paginator html ?

Comment: yes, posted edits above

Comment: nou sure if it is a typo here or on your code => newMatTableDataSource<DataTableRow(this.dataTableData);  ->    new MatTableDataSource(this.dataTableData);

Comment: can you recreate your problem in this blitzy https://stackblitz.com/angular/jrgeaglyqxr?file=app%2Fpaginator-overview-example.ts

Comment: I was able to recreate but unable to save in stackblitz, classic i think i know the issue though...

Answer (score 0):

```
"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.5",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
```

needs to be:

```
"@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
```

If it's the first one you will get a cryptic error on the MatTooltip on the data table